# Customize UISLider to change the color after the thumb is dragged

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uislider

I have this type of a custom `UISlider` I have implemented that looks like this:
[image]

The peculiarity of it is that you can't drag it to the left of it's initial thumb position.

But when you drag it to the right it should change the color of the path like this leaving the color on the left as it was and colouring the path it has travelled:

[image]

I am only aware of the two properties of `UISlider` - `MinimumTrackImage` and `MaximumTrackImage` that are responsible for the right and the left side of the handle.

How do I implement this strange behaviour? Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this will actually work but try creating a new custom minimum track image that has the old color on the left (and as wide as the initial thumb value) and the new color on the right (just two pixels wide). Then call `resizableImageWithCapInsets` with a `left` value matching the thumb value and the `right` value of 1.

Comment: @rmaddy That's an awesome idea, but how do you transfer thumb value into pixels?

Comment: Convert your thumb value to a percent (0.0 to 1.0). Multiply that by the width of the `UISlider`.

Comment: @rmaddy The idea was great but unfortunately I could not implement it as hard as I tried. I'll keep on looking for the answer for this task, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to implement this with the following code. The tricky part to figure out was how to set the initial image based on the starting value of the slider. I did that by creating a 4 pixel wide image with the left 2 pixels your starting left color, and the right 2 pixels, the color you want after the drag. Basically, I stretched that image (on left only) to fill an image view, then got that image with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(). I then create another stretchable image with that image with stretching only on the right.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *slider;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat previousValue;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    self.previousValue = self.slider.value;
    if (self.slider.value > .01) {
        UIImage *newImage = [self imageStretchedOnLeft];
        UIImage *rightStretchImage = [newImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, newImage.size.width -2, 0, 0) resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
        [self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:rightStretchImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else{
        [self.slider setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OneColor.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

}

-(IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)slider {
    if (slider.value < self.previousValue) {
        slider.value = self.previousValue;
    }
    self.previousValue = slider.value;
}

- (UIImage *)imageStretchedOnLeft {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TwoColor.png"]; // 4 pixel wide 1 pixel high image. Left 2 pixels are original track color, right two are new drag color
    UIImage *cappedImage = [image resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 2)];

    UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.slider.frame.size.width * (self.slider.value/self.slider.maximumValue), self.slider.frame.size.height)];
    iv.image = cappedImage;
    [self.view insertSubview:iv belowSubview:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(iv.frame.size, YES, [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
    [iv.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [iv removeFromSuperview];

    return img;
}
```

I get a graphics context error if the slider's value is 0, so the if statement in the viewDidAppear method uses a different one color image if that value is less that .01.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for the idea, this was a fun one to work on. I'm guessing that there's a better way to get an image than the way I do it here with an image view hidden under the current view. Do you know how to get an image from an "offscreen view"?

Comment: That's a great idea, I'll try it out and report back later with the results!

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
//code for slider
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"];

[[UISlider appearance] setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UISlider appearance] setThumbImage:thumbImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Here is nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5) of raywenderlich

Comment: I am **already** using them. How will those methods let me keep **part** of the image as it was and change the color for the path of the thumb?

Comment: I think my question states it clearly enough - trace the path of the thumb and place a green image where it went.

Comment: in rayWenderlich code, its changing path of both left and right after moving

Comment: Does it make the left path two-colored?

Comment: Please, sir, if you don't understand the question, stop being silly and please delete your answer and never come back again, OK?